# Is it possible to automatically start a VPN connection when either a wired or wireless network connection is present?

Tags: networking, windows-8, vpn

As the question title says:

Is it possible to automatically start a VPN connection when either a wired or wireless network connection is present on Windows 8?

Is there an event code or such that is triggered when either a wired or wireless network connection is present (that I could then use in Scheduled Tasks or such).

Answer (score 0):

Create a scheduled task upon an event:

Log: Microsoft-Windows-NetworkProfile/Operational
Source: NetworkProfile
Event ID: 10000

The 10000 Event ID is logged when you connect to a network.

Source: http://www.groovypost.com/howto/automatically-run-script-on-internet-connect-network-connection-drop/

Comment: Thanks. I take it a VPN connection does not trigger this event code (causing an endless loop)?